# What is the most efficient design to use when constructing a bell siphon

Tags: aquaponics

I have seen many different designs for bell siphons.  I was wondering if there was one specific type of bell siphon that is generally known to be the best design.  ...the most kinks worked out of it.

Comment: This does seem like a shopping recommendation question, and in general, Stack Exchanges don't do those. Let's discuss on meta.

Comment: A shopping recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the best over all design I have seen is provided by Affnan, Rob Torcellini, and TCLynx.  Affnan has expanded on Murray Hallam's original design using a venturi on the internal stand pipe to create better suction. Rob introduced a j tube set up under the tank connected to the stand pipe to create additional back pressure - which once broken also expands on the total suction.  And TCLynx adds another tidbit of great information: make sure your drain pipe is a larger diameter than your input pipe.

http://affnan-aquaponics.blogspot.com/2010/05/siphon-revised.html

All of these tidbits allow for a slow fill and fast drain but in a manner that drastically reduces the cost of ownership to keep these systems moving.

**Update**
This link has newer/better details: http://affnan-aquaponics.blogspot.com/2011/04/mini-siphon-improving-previous-design.html